# WildFly 10.x eclipse plugin fail to copy all files under webapp to the server location

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10, jboss-tools

I'm using **Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)** and using **JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools version 3.2.4.v20170510-2349**. I have a java web maven project. This is part of an EAR project which I deploy to **WildFly 10.1.0 final**. The project structure is as below.

```
myApp
   src > main > webapp > static
                       > test
                       > .
                       > .
                       > WEB-INF
```

I have all my static files (such as .js files) in **static** folder.
The problem is when I publish to my server everything will get copied except the content under **webapp** folder (files and folders are copied partially). For example, I can see that the test folder will get copied each time but not the **staic** folder or other folders.

I tried deploying on tomcat and everything is working fine. Maybe there is something wrong with the JBOSS Tools. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Have you some logs when you deploy on wildfly ?

Comment: I found the issue. In our pom.xml we have a line in the maven-war-plugin which we excluded some folders using packagingExcludes. This exclusions were not respected by Tomcat and WAS Eclipse server tools when we were testing/deploying on Tomcat and WAS but WildFly server tool respected those exclusions. When I removed the exclusion everything  was copied to the server